# Migrating a MVC4 project to MVC5 What about Userprofiles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I had an MVC4 project designed using VS2012 which I migrated to MVC5. I am not using OAuth or external logins in my project.

I am now in a dilemma because my old project used the default Simple Membership and related database schema. But now I am migrating to a newer version, and the default database schema is very different.

I can use my custom tables but need help with migrating my users. Since the database membership schema is different I am really confused and don't know how to go about it. The only thing I can think about is regenerating user password and emailing them to my users and hoping that they read the email.

Is there any other way/method I can use to migrate my users to new database schema without fiddling with their passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS 2013, when you create a File-->New Project-->MVC, the default authentication mechanism is set to **Individual User Accounts** which in turn creates a project using the new ASP.NET Identity stuff.

This turns out to include a bunch of new libraries such as:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll
- Many other dlls

In addition, the project template also adds a new `IdentityModels.cs` file within the Models folder.

Looking at that file, you’ll notice an `ApplicationUser` class that implements `IdentityUser`.

There is also an `ApplicationDbContext` etc...
Looking inside the `AccountController`, you’ll see a `UserManager` property.

All of this new stuff is what is related to the new ASP.NET Identity

---

If you were to create a new project but this time, change the authentication mechanism to **No Authentication** you’d notice that none of the new ASP.NET Identity stuff is in there.

---

In VS 2012, when you create a new project and select `Internet Application`, by default it will use `SimpleMembership` thanks to the `WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData` dlls (that are not present inside an MVC 5.0 application by the way).

In addition, if you look at the `AccountController`, you’ll notice the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` action filter which triggers the creation of your database.

---

So far I haven’t answered your question but my understanding (and I do have to mention that I have not tried or tested this) is that you could continue to use `SimpleMembership` within an ASP.NET MVC 5.0 application as long (of course) as you’re not including any of the ASP.NET Identity stuff previously mentioned.

When you say “*I am migrating to a newer version*” do you mean that you’re simply updating the version of the MVC dll’s?

**OR**

Do you mean that you are now using the new ASP.NET Identity stuff and you are now looking for a way to migrate your users from the SimpleMembership to the new Identity TABLES?

Like I said, I have not tried migrating from MVC 4.0 to 5.0 but if I had to do it, I would only upgrade the MVC dll’s and other stuff here and there **WITHOUT** touching or adding anything relevant to ASP.NET Identity.

I would continue to use SimpleMembership.

Not sure if this will help (or not) but this is my understanding of things.

Otherwise, you may want to have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688804/migrating-existing-users-from-mvc-4-simplemembership-to-mvc-5-asp-net-identity)